# Execute git command in Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to handle a git script in VSTS tasks with Powershell, but it's not working as expected.

What I'm doing is fetching latest commits messages after the latest tag to put inside a *Release Notes*, this is the base git command:

```
git log `git describe --tags --abbrev=0`..HEAD --no-decorate --no-merges --abbrev=0 --pretty=format:"%s"
```

But Powershell doesn't accept this format, so I do the following:

```
$latestTag = git describe --tags --abbrev=0
$releaseNotes = git log $latestTag..HEAD --no-decorate --no-merges --abbrev=0 --pretty=format:"%s"
```

It seems that when I put the variable `$latestTag` next to `..HEAD` it breaks line, if I specify the tag eg. `v1.2.9` instead of the variable it works well.

What can I do to make it run properly ?
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but try enclosing `$latestTag..HEAD` in `"`

Comment: It worked, latest build was cached, it's now returning the value! Could you please post it so I can accept  @MarkAdelsberger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enclose the expression `$latestTag..HEAD` in `"` marks, as

```
$latestTag = git describe --tags --abbrev=0
$releaseNotes = git log "$latestTag..HEAD" --no-decorate --no-merges --abbrev=0 --pretty=format:"%s"
```

This has something to do with how PowerShell expands variables, but I don't use PS enough to *really* understand it.

Comment: A guess I'd say it stops PowerShell from interpreting the `..` as a range operator (ie range of 1 to 10 being `1..10`) and instead as a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it on a single line you might be able to try the powershell syntax for embedding a comment with something like your original.  Translating to powershell-friendly statements I think it would be something like

```
git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --no-decorate --no-merges --abbrev=0 --pretty=format:"%s"
```

This should resolve the expression inside `$()` and then insert that result as text to the `git log` command much like your original.